# How to obtain coordinates from points with similar symbol in an image?

Tags: qgis, symbology, coordinates, image

I would like to obtain a table containing all the coordinates of the triangles in the following image.

[image]

I know it is possible to georeference my map using the georeferencing plugin and then I can access the coordinates of any point using the Copy_Coords plugin. But this takes much time and I would like to know if you know a way to do it faster ?

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137989/how-to-automatically-convert-dots-on-paper-maps-to-vector-points/)

Comment: If possibly I would try to get the data from the source owner....

Comment: I back @Jakob suggestion. I can see overlapping markers in dense areas so these aren't going to be easy to convert... find out who owns the data and ask for a clip - it's the only way to be sure you have complete and accurate data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unsupervised classification methods; But it is too much hassle to recommend it

Comment: Can you expand on why it's too much hassle... you and I both know that it's not sutable but for future readers contemplating it it would be good to give an outline of the methodology showing why it's shouldn't be considered; also, in a slightly different case it might be workable and totally worth the effort.